# Tomcat server 9.0 not starting in eclipse It showing error "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Tomcat server 9.0 not starting in eclipse It showing error "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.", I have tried everything from changing port to killing process and I also uninstalled tomcat and eclipse and installed again but it is same error, Help me with it ,or show any path to free my occupied port if it reserved ,thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Is there any log output or output in the Console view to work off of?

Comment: Most probably there happened an error when starting some of your deployed applications. You must read the console output (as @nitind said) to get further information.

Comment: I search almost every cave for the answer.Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

**The most easiest solution to this problem** is (this worked for me) :
Follow the steps :
**1.In eclipse go to the servers tab and delete the server by right click on it and delete.
(Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost [Stopped,Republish]).**
**2.Now right click there go to new then click Server.**
**3.Now go to Configure run time environments and select Apache Tomcat v9.0 and remove it and click ok.**
**4.Now click next and finish.**
**5.Now go to the project and try to run it using right click on the project and run as , run on Server.**

- That's it(this will work). I'm definitely sure this should work. Hope
  this answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

On the server tab click on the first line and remove (right click) any children projects that can conflict with your project